# To Check google site access permission from App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites

Is it possible to check whether one have access to Google site using the site url in Apps Script?
My requirement is that when someone clicks on google site link and if they don't have access then they should be redirected to custom Access denied page.

I tried using UrlFetchApp but it didn't return anything relevant in order to distinguish whether one has the access to google site or not.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally **SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(link)** helped to resolve my issue. If it throws an exception that means user don't have access to the site.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/sites-app#getsitebyurlurl)